# What are the roles of EJBs in Java EE?

Tags: hibernate, ejb

I am new to Java Enterprise Edition, and have already read about servlets and JSPs. What does Java EE contain? I mean, is it necessary to read about EJBs? What are the roles of EJBs in Java EE?

What about Hibernate? Do both EJBs and Hibernate do the same thing?

Comment: yeah i know bt Im Confused please help me to figure out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Java EE 5, EJBs are really just ordinary Java objects with a few additional behaviours added, primarily:

1. Dependencies are automatically injected into their fields
2. Their methods are automatically exported to remote clients via RMI
3. Security checks are automatically applied to invocations of their methods
4. Transactions are automatically wrapped around invocations of their methods

There are a few other services that are specifically available to EJBs, such as asynchronous invocations, timers, and coupling to message queues.

If you think any of those things would be useful, then you should consider using EJBs. If you're learning about Java EE, then you definitely need to learn about EJBs, so that you can make an informed decision about whether to use them or not.

It's worth noting that in modern Java EE, there is a standard called [Contexts and Dependency Injection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html) (CDI) which can be used to obtain many of the benefits of EJBs, and may be preferable. You should definitely also learn about CDI.

Many web applications are built without any EJBs at all. Most web applications user either CDI or some earlier, non-standard, equivalent such as Spring or Guice.

Hibernate is an implementation of the [Java Persistence Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) (JPA) standard. JPA is about persisting objects to a database, and provides completely different services to EJB. You would use JPA for your entity objects (which capture the structure and fundamental behaviour of your data), and EJB or CDI for your service objects (which capture the specific business logic of your application).

Earlier versions of EJB did also provide persistence of EJBs, and so had some overlap with JPA, but that is only of historical interest now.

Comment: >`(CDI) which can be used to obtain many of the benefits of EJBs` - Or can be used together. The model is currently defined such that things like CDI scopes and the more versatile CDI injection can be applied to EJB beans. By far not all container services are available for CDI beans yet, but with every release of Java EE more and more EJB services are retrofitted into CDI extensions.

Comment: Indeed. I slightly regret mentioning CDI, because it's impossible to give a fair treatment of it without writing hundreds of words, and this answer didn't seem the right place to do that. The take-home message for @Amritpal is that he should understand both EJB and CDI well enough to use each of them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is too broad to answer that but in short EJB technology is the core of J2EE. It enables developers to write reusable and portable server-side business logic for the J2EE platform.

From [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29978&seqNum=3):-

> **Roles specified in EJB specifications.**
>
> An application assembler is responsible for packaging all the
>   necessary EJB jar files and any other jar files, including resource
>   adapter .rar files, into an assembled business application. Note that
>   assembling does not mean installing and deploying the application; it
>   means bringing together the various application components necessary
>   for the application, and changing the individual components deployment
>   descriptors as necessary.
>
> The deployer takes the assembled application, and deploys it in a
>   specific run-time operational environment consisting of an EJB server
>   and EJB containers. Although it is not necessary that the EJB server
>   and EJB container be provided by the same vendor, in most cases it is
>   (especially because the current specifications assume that the EJB
>   container provider also supplies the EJB server). Any configurations
>   required by the components are also handled by the deployer, who uses
>   a deployment tool to install all external software that the
>   application components depend on.
>
> The EJB container provider is responsible for supplying a server and
>   container that conform to the EJB 2.0 architecture specifications. The
>   EJB container is a hosting environment for EJB instances. The
>   container also has a deployment management tool that enables the
>   deployer to manage J2EE applications.
>
> The system administrator's role is much broader than just maintaining
>   the J2EE environments. A system administrator is also responsible for
>   managing the EIS environment and monitoring the distributed
>   environment. No specific system administration and monitoring
>   contracts are specified in the EJB specifications. Neither are any
>   similar contracts defined in the JCA specifications. Thus, for the
>   most part, the system administration and monitoring function is
>   customized to match the specific enterprise's requirements.

---

> **Does both are same.**

No Hibernate and EJB are not same. I would suggest you to go to the [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnblr.html)